# Why is `enum of enum of enum..` allowed?

Tags: java, syntax, enums

I cannot understand why this even compile.
I've tried with different formats and they all seem to work..

why is it legal to have an `enum of enum of enum of..`?

```
interface I {

    enum E implements I {
        VAL;
    }

    class Test {
        I.E         f1 = I.E.VAL;
        I.E.E       f2 = I.E.VAL;
        I.E.E.E     f3 = I.E.VAL;
        I.E.E.E.E.E f4 = I.E.VAL;

        I.E v1 = I.E.VAL;
        I.E v2 = I.E.E.VAL;
        I.E v3 = I.E.E.E.E.E.E.VAL;
        I.E v4 = I.E.E.E.E.E.E.E.E.E.E.VAL;
    }
}
```

My IDE reports it compiles just fine, although `I.E.E` does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `I` interface contains an enum type named `E`.

This type implements that same `I` interface, so it inherits everything that that interface contains.
This includes the `E` type itself.

In other words, `I.E.E` is accessing `I.E` as inherited by `E` from the outer `I`.

Comment: Java *could have* made the inheritance rules for interfaces simpler. Taking advantage of this rule rarely ever makes any sense (even without the infinite recursion demonstrated here).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: You can do this with classes too.

Comment: there is no infinite recursion going on here.

Comment: @slaks Of course you can, but at least with classes it is kind-of less awkward due to single inheritance. Inheriting nested types from an interface just feels wrong.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik This is a circular reference, rather than an infinite loop caused by recursion.

Comment: Is it possible to actually make a concrete class that implements `I`? I can't imagine it would be.

Comment: @TheodoreLogan The shown source code creates an equivalence relation `E = E.E`, which means that the expansion rule `E -> E.E` is an identity type transformation; this rule can be recursively applied *ad infinitum*. It happened that this picture was in my head while I was writing the parenthetical clarification of my chatty comment above. But, if you see any value in that comment, and feel that the "circular reference" designation is vital to understanding it, I welcome your explanation.

Comment: just because a rule can be APPLIED indefinitely it doesnt have to do anything with recursion nor even infinite recursion - you were simply using the wrong words, just like i already said. With your knowledge, you should know better than that - using proper terms is absolutely vital if you want to communicate information of any kind. One can also create an array with objects in it which call each others methods infinitely and recursively - that doesnt make the array infinitely recursing in itself.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I personally do not think the context in which you used the term 'infinite recursion' would seriously confuse anyone. In any case it seems irrelevant, specializt could have just typed out a sentence to clarify his reasoning in the first place and educate readers rather than causing this unproductive conversation to take place.

Comment: Thanks for a voice of reason, @TheodoreLogan. I hope we can now conclude this unproductive exchange.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: there is no special rule defining what has been shown in this question. Actually this is the consequence of a very simple rule: interface implementations inherit every member of the interface. If you think you could describe a simpler rule than that, I would like to hear it…

Comment: @Holger It is the simplicity of *consequences* that counts, not of the sentence describing it. Inheritance of member types can only confuse, for example the intuitive meaning of `HashMap.Entry` is completely wrong---unless reality has heavily hammered the correct intuition into you.

Comment: @Holger Look at this beauty: `for (HashMap.Entry<Object,Object> e : new TreeMap<>().entrySet()) System.out.println(e);` Now tell me how your stomach feels.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: that’s even worse as it doesn’t compile with Oracle’s jdk1.7 (but does with others) as there’s indeed a (`private`) `HashMap.Entry` class. However, the problem you describe is not connected to interfaces at all. The same applies for inner classes of non-`interface` classes, e.g. `HashMap.SimpleEntry e=new TreeMap.SimpleEntry(x, y);`, and it even works for non- `static` inner classes. What’s your proposed solution, abrogate inheritance at all? It doesn’t help calling for “simplicity of consequences” when you can’t formulate comprehensible rules leading to them.

Comment: @Holger As I mentioned above, with interfaces this is at its worst due to a) multiple inheritance and b) counterintuitiveness of inheriting anything but method-based API from an interface---but it doesn't help with classes, either. Yes, I would choose no inheritance of static members and member types. Cross-reference the only modern choice Java designers had: inheritance of interface's static methods. They chose none.

Comment: @Holger Just a terminology note: "inner class" is the opposite of "static class". They form the dichotomy of the concept "nested class".